# iTextSharp HTML file to PDF conversion issues

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

I'm working on creating a single PDF from two separate HTML (tables, fonts, div mostly) files. I created two methods, one to create a PDF from each file and another to merge the two. The only problem that occurs is with the final PDF; when using the Pechkin wrapper the PDF displays as intended, but when using HTMLWorker or XMLWorkerHelper the PDF does not display as intended. Since I would prefer to use the same library for both the conversion and merging, is there a way to adjust iTextSharp to create an accurate PDF? Is there another open source that has a converter and merger that I should use instead?

Comment: *does not display as intended* - this is not very clear.

Comment: Sorry for being vague....Text isn't aligned properly, spacing is wrong, some lines do not even display, no titles.